# Catel (MVVM framework) [AS] doesn't return right assembly name

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

I'm experimenting and trying to understand the Catel framework.

I understand that Catel has a Naming convention to register Views and viewmodels. 
According to documentation the `[AS]` convention, should be replaced by the assembly name.
This is not the case for me and I have to manually write the assembly name as follow:

```
string aSSname = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
var viewLocator = serviceLocator.ResolveType<IViewLocator>();
viewLocator.NamingConventions.Add(aSSname + ".Views.[VM]Window");
```

The following code dose NOT work for me:

```
viewLocator.NamingConventions.Add("[AS]"+ ".Views.[VM]Window");
```

**More Info (*if its help*):**

All the Code above is placed in `App.xaml.cs`

I load viewModel as separate assembly:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PreloadAssemblies(typeof (App).Assembly.GetDirectory());
```

to sum up, How can I make this example to work with `[AS]` convention.

***My Guess:***

My guess is that viewLocator is looking in the wrong assembly. 
probably looking in the same assembly were the viewModels are.

if this is right, how can I change the `viewLocator` so it search in the correct Assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catel can only know about the [AS] of the type which is used to resolve the view. So if you are using [AS] in a type in a MyProject.Views assembly, it cannot resolve view models in the MyProject.ViewModels assembly.

In that case you must simply specify the naming convention with the expected assembly name (such as MyProject.Views.[VM]View

You can also do this dynamically yourself by using reflection and resolving all namespaces that contains .Views. in the assemblies that are in the TypeCache of Catel.